# Using stat_summary to produce individualized boxplots with aes(group = ...)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I tried to produce 12 boxplots per ggplots `stat_summary()` functions, as you can see below in the reproducible example. I used `stat_summary()` instead of `geom_boxplot()`, because I want to whiskers to end at the 1st and 99th percentile of the data or to be individualized so to speak. I coded two functions, one for the whiskers and one for the outliers and used them as arguments in `stat_summary()`. This is the result:
[image]

I see two problems with this plot:

1. Not all outliers are coloured in red.
2. Outliers cut the whiskers, which is not supposed to happen by definition of my functions.

The help file has not been helping me in solving this issue. Comments are welcome.

The code:

```
library(stats)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Example Data
{
  set.seed(123)
  
  indexnumber_of_entity = rep(c(1:30),
              each = 12)
  
  month = rep(c(1:12), 
             each = 1, 
             times = 30)
  
  variable_of_interest = runif(n = 360,
                               min = 0,
                               max = 100)
  
  Data = as.data.frame(cbind(indexnumber_of_entity,
                            month,
                            variable_of_interest)) %>% mutate_at(.vars = c(1,2,3),
                                                                 as.numeric)
  Data_Above_99th_Percentile = filter(Data,
                                      variable_of_interest > stats::quantile(Data$variable_of_interest,
                                                                             0.99))
  Data_Below_1st_Percentile = filter(Data,
                                     variable_of_interest < stats::quantile(Data$variable_of_interest,
                                                                            0.01))
}

# Functions that enable individualizing boxplots
{
  Individualized_Boxplot_Quantiles <- function(x){
    d <- data.frame(ymin = stats::quantile(x,0.01),
                    lower = stats::quantile(x,0.25),
                    middle = stats::quantile(x,0.5),
                    upper = stats::quantile(x,0.75),
                    ymax = stats::quantile(x,0.99),
                    row.names = NULL)
    d[1, ]
  }
  
  Definition_of_Outliers = function(x) 
  {
    subset(x, 
           stats::quantile(x,0.99) < x | stats::quantile(x,0.01) > x)
  }
}

# Producing the ggplot
ggplot(data = Data) + 
  
  aes(x = month,
      y = variable_of_interest,
      group = month) +
  
  stat_summary(fun.data = Individualized_Boxplot_Quantiles, 
               geom="boxplot",
               lwd = 0.5) +
  
  stat_summary(fun.y = Definition_of_Outliers, 
               geom="point",
               size = 1) + 
  
  labs(title = "Distributions of Variable of Interest based on months",
       x = "Month",
       y = "Variable of Interest") + 
  
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20,
                                  hjust = 0.5, 
                                  face = "bold"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12,
                                   face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12,
                                   face = "bold"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16,
                                    face = "bold",
                                    vjust = -3),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16,
                                    face = "bold",
                                    vjust = 3)) + 
  
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(seq(from = 1,
                                    to = 12,
                                    by = 1))) +
  
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(seq(from = 0,
                                    to = 100,
                                    by = 10))) + 
  
  geom_point(data = Data_Above_99th_Percentile,
             colour = "red",
             size = 1) + 
  
  geom_point(data = Data_Below_1st_Percentile,
             colour = "red",
             size = 1)
```

Comment: If you supply some sample data that will really help you to get a good answer here.

Comment: @Allan ah yes I forgot to put in the code before posting ^^

Comment: I have had a look over this, and I don't think there's much wrong with your code as such. It pretty much does what I would expect. You only have 30 observations per month, so the 1st and 99th centile are going to encompass all the observations for each group except the single lowest and single highest values. The whiskers are going to be extremely close to the outlier points since they are at 99%, and though they may not quite touch the outlying points, they will appear to because the points have a non-zero radius when they are drawn. I'm not sure what you want to fix here.

Comment: @AllanCameron I see how this might seem to be related to the number of observations, but I find it difficult to explain, how some points are colored, and some or not. I think that this indicates, that ```stat_summary()```, based on my functions, produces different points as outliers than the ```geom_points()``` do based on the 99th and the 1st percentile. So I do actually see a issue here.

Comment: Your stat summaries are correct. The issue is that your `Data_Above_99th_Percentile` and `Data_Below_1st_Percentile` are not groupwise calculations. If you group by month when creating these data frames, you will get consistent results. I'll demo below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the functions a little bit like this:

```r
boxplot_quantiles <- function(x) {
  y <- as.data.frame(t(stats::quantile(x, c(0.01, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.99))))
  setNames(y, c('ymin', 'lower', 'middle', 'upper', 'ymax'))
}

outliers <- function(x) {
  subset(x, stats::quantile(x,0.99) < x | stats::quantile(x,0.01) > x)
}
```

You can rely on the summary functions, since the `Data_above_99th_Percentile` and `Data_Below_1st_Percentile` were not groupwise calculations in your own code.

```r
ggplot(data = Data, aes(x = month, y = variable_of_interest, group = month)) +
  stat_summary(fun = outliers, geom = "point", col = 'red', size = 1) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = boxplot_quantiles, geom = "boxplot", lwd = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous('Month', breaks = 1:12) +
  scale_y_continuous('Variable of Interest' , breaks = 0:10 * 10) +
  labs(title = "Distributions of Variable of Interest based on months") + 
  theme(text = element_text(face = 'bold', size = 12),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16, margin = margin(20, 0, 0, 0)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16, vjust = 3))
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

As long as you perform groupwise operations on the filtered data frames, your alternative method of drawing the outliers will work too. Note that I have added these in colored layers above the existing plot so that the red points are overplotted with blue and green dots:

```r
Data_Above_99th_Percentile <- Data %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  filter(variable_of_interest > quantile(variable_of_interest,0.99))

Data_Below_1st_Percentile <- Data %>% 
  group_by(month) %>%
  filter(variable_of_interest < quantile(variable_of_interest, 0.01))


ggplot(data = Data, aes(x = month, y = variable_of_interest, group = month)) +
  stat_summary(fun = outliers, geom = "point", col = 'red', size = 1) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = boxplot_quantiles, geom = "boxplot", lwd = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous('Month', breaks = 1:12) +
  scale_y_continuous('Variable of Interest' , breaks = 0:10 * 10) +
  labs(title = "Distributions of Variable of Interest based on months") + 
  theme(text = element_text(face = 'bold', size = 12),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16, margin = margin(20, 0, 0, 0)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16, vjust = 3)) +
  geom_point(data = Data_Below_1st_Percentile, color = 'green') +
  geom_point(data = Data_Above_99th_Percentile, color = 'blue')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for pointing out that mistake. In a comment above, you said I could use the dataframe ```Data_Above_99th_Percentile```, if I group by month when creating those. Can you elaborate on this? Maybe you can provide a small example?